# I have some issue in bounty award process

Tags: discussion, bounty

I have set bounty for one of my question for proper answer, but according to your option, bounty will be awarded to user that posted answer first even if that is not fruitful.

What should I do now.
Can I able to edit the option that allow me to get proper answer on my question.

If yes, which option is appropriate for this?

My bounty question info [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/302356/magento2-i-want-to-show-featured-product-on-top-of-the-category-and-search-resu).

Answer (score 2):

the bounty will be awarded to the first post you **accept** as an answer. So choose your answer carefully!

Comment: If I not accept any answer then?

Comment: @Purushotam Sharma If you do not accept any answer then the most voted answer will get  50% of bounty.

Comment: If bounty expired and I am not getting suitable answer then bounty is awarded to user?

Comment: @PurushotamSharma, then also highest voted  answer gets 50%